# Even after reformatting, shutdown takes very long

Tags: ssd, windows-8.1, shutdown

Help! Ever since I added an SSD drive in my laptop and even after deleting all partitions in SSD and installing windows 8.1 super fresh in SSD, it does not shutdown immediately. This has been a problem ever since. Is Windows a problem in SSD?

Comment: does this happen in a minimal boot configuration?

Comment: Could you express “very long” in numbers, please?

Comment: I stopwatched it and it took 5:10 seconds to shutdown but less than 10 seconds to boot

Comment: Does it take a long time to restart too? Are you using Windows 8.1 certified drivers? What are your technical specifications?

Comment: Yes. I tried searching if SSD is compatible with GPT and I saw one which said it does not support GPT. Does it??

Comment: What are windows 8.1 certified drivers? Asus x550cc intel i5 3rd gen 4gb ram 500hhd (caddy) and 120gb ssd. Nvidia 720m. Right now, i just installed windows 8.1 mbr but it behaves still the same :-(

Comment: capture a shutdown trace: http://pastebin.com/RFRkuc81

Comment: Here it is. http://www.2shared.com/file/b1kt_anp/shutdown_BASELATENCYDISPATCHER.html   why is it that the analysis only logs 6 seconds wherein the computer restarts more than 5 mins?

Answer (score 1):

According to the trace, Windows shuts down fully in 6.9s and shutting down all services takes 5s:

```
<timing shutdownTime="6940" servicesShutdownDuration="5000">
```

If it takes longer than it is hardware related.

Comment: That's weird. Because if it is Ubuntu, it shutdowns immediately. I used to dual boot my computer, ubuntu in ssd, and windows 8.1 in ssd. Windows takes 5 mins to shutdown. (The laptop status led on is still lit for 5 mins)  while ubuntu shutdowns immediately. Both of them are in gpt partition. Last night, I deleted all OS partitions and only installed windows 8.1 in ssd,, tried first in gpt, then mbr, but still the same. If it is hardware related, then ubuntu should have behaved the same..

Comment: Ok. Yesterday, my Windows shutdowns pretty fast. After another try, the problem persisted. It seemed the problem is inconsistent. Maybe it has something to do with the  bios firmware??

Comment: Windows 8 uses a new shutdown (logoff + hibernation). Is regular hibernation slow or fast?

Comment: It has no hibernate option.

Comment: enable it first: http://www.redmondpie.com/enable-windows-8-hibernate-mode-option-how-to-tutorial/